# Site Map JQuery Style.. using attr. plus page urls

Tags: jquery

So I have a looping example of site url string and trying to add pages to the links, but I don't want to have to deal with the domain as it's fixed.  Right now it doesn't work.. but I'm trying to fix it.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    url =  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));

       $('#sitemap a').attr('href','http://site.com/?c=123&p='+url);

    });
    </script>

    // trying to get output  http://site.com/?c=123&p=page1.html
    <div id="sitemap">
    <a href="page1.html">test</a>
    <a href="page2.html">test</a>
    <a href="page3.html">test</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: _How_ doesn't it work? Explain what problems you're having, and you might get an answer.

Comment: I'm trying to get the output of http://site.com/?c=123&p=page1.html on the links inside the #sitemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you wan to do is actually:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#sitemap a').each(function () {
             // Cache the jQuery object
             var current = $(this);

             // Get the current url
             var currentUrl = current.attr('href');

             // Replace the current url with the new one (appending the url above)
             current.attr('href', 'http://site.com/?c=123&p=' + currentUrl);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this line of code that you wrote, `this` actually refers to `document`. And `document` doesn't have an attribute called `href`.

```
url =  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href'));
```